# Adding cocos2d files to xcode project?

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I am doing collision based game.So i added Cocos2d files such as Box2d,FontLabel,cocoslive etc.But while running the project am getting two errors in following code... What is the reason for this.Any changes want to be done in info.plist and build settings.Please help to find.

```
sweepA.Normalize();
sweepB.Normalize();
```

this code is in b2TimeOfImpact.cpp(Box2d,collision)class.
am getting the error "No member named "Normalize" in 'b2Sweep'".

Comment: have you included header with b2Sweep interface? b2Math.h, as i remember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you see coco2ds template in your xcode

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/1412

try creating project from scratch through template .